# Login loop after update or disk resize

Tags: login

I had to liveboot and resize one of the disks and after restarting it said something about an update so I had to wait sometime longer and when I tried loggin in after that, I was in a login loop - I have looked online and I nothing seems to help

Any ideas?

Comment: can you login in *tty mode*? use the keyboard shortcut **Ctrl** + **Alt** + **F1** to be in tty mode, **Ctrl** + **Alt** + **F7** to return in graphic mode

Comment: If there is insufficient space in $HOME (your user directory), and the gui cannot create the needed working files for the gui to operate, the login fails and you get returned to login screen (no error message is shown on screen; a login loop that only occurs in gui).  However the tty (text terminals) still work, so you can login there and see if you have run out (or near out) of disk space in $HOME; if you have - you need to delete files in $HOME (your user directory partition).

Comment: Yes I can login via tty, ill resize again but I doubt thats the issue, thanks

Comment: I can login in tty but resizing to get more space did not solve it